# Appdelegate working for iPhone, but not for iPad version

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I use appdelegate to share some variables between my app classes like this :

> MyAppDelegate *objDelegate=(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication
>   sharedApplication] delegate];

then I use like this :

> var=objDelegate.var;

I have no problem in the iPhone version, but when I test in the iPad Simulator, I get null for the value of the objDelegate vars.

I should say that I converted my app from iPhone only to Universal, as I said I still get no problem with iPhone version, what's wrong with iPad version ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, converting your app to universal, creates two delegate classes that subclass the a main app delegate. Are you sure you're accessing the right class?

Comment: You are right, I read about this, but I am sure that I havn't ipad delegate class, only one delegate for all the app.